# There is a translator code on every text box in WordPress pages

Tags: wordpress, elementor, translators

I work on Elementor WordPress and this code appears in every textbox :

```
translator
 
Afrikaans
Albanian - shqipe
Arabic - ‎‫العربية‬‎
Armenian - Հայերէն
Azerbaijani - azərbaycanca
Basque - euskara
Belarusian - беларуская
Bengali - বাংলা
Bulgarian - български
Catalan - català
Chinese - 中文（简体中文）
Chinese - 中文 (繁體中文)
Croatian - hrvatski
Czech - čeština
Danish - dansk
Dutch - Nederlands
English
Esperanto - esperanto
Estonian - eesti
Filipino
Finnish - suomi
French - français
Galician - galego
Georgian - ქართული
German - Deutsch
Greek - Ελληνικά
Gujarati - ગુજરાતી
Haitian Creole - kreyòl ayisyen
Hebrew - ‎‫עברית‬‎
Hindi - हिन्दी
Hungarian - magyar
Icelandic - íslenska
Indonesian - Bahasa Indonesia
Irish - Gaeilge
Italian - italiano
Japanese - 日本語
Kannada - ಕನ್ನಡ
Korean - 한국어
Latin - Lingua Latina
Latvian - latviešu
Lithuanian - lietuvių
Macedonian - македонски
Malay - Bahasa Melayu
Maltese - Malti
Norwegian - norsk
Persian - ‎‫فارسی‬‎
Polish - polski
Portuguese - português
Romanian - română
Russian - русский
Serbian - Српски
Slovak - slovenčina
Slovenian - slovenščina
Spanish - español
Swahili - Kiswahili
Swedish - svenska
Tamil - தமிழ்
Telugu - తెలుగు
Thai - ไทย
Turkish - Türkçe
Ukrainian - українська
Urdu - ‎‫اردو‬‎
Vietnamese - Tiếng Việt
Welsh - Cymraeg
Yiddish - יידיש
Double-click
Select to translate
```

I want to either remove it or hide it because it distorts the layout and the text after it disappears

Comment: This seems is related to a browser translation plugin or a WordPress translation plugin. So disable the responsible plugin.